# get the string between 3rd and 4th space using regexp_substr

Tags: sql, oracle

i have one of my table column(SR) date in the below format:

```
SR Creation Time: 17-Feb-2022 11:37:31 CST
```

From this i need to extract the date(17-Feb-2022) only.
I tried using regexp_substr with some option,but could not get the exact output.
Can you please suggest.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use @ekochergin's answer, but there is a way to do exactly what you asked...

```
SELECT
  regexp_substr(
    'SR Creation Time: 17-Feb-2022 11:37:31 CST',
    '([^[:space:]]+)',  -- matches 1 or more non-space characters
    1,                  -- starts from 1st character of search string
    4                   -- returns 4th successful match
  )
FROM
  DUAL
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2d84559be9718e8bb4954a2c9afdd3f2

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting spaces, you may just parse date out if date format is always same

```
SELECT regexp_substr('SR Creation Time: 17-Feb-2022 11:37:31 CST', '[0-9]{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}')
  FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need the TO_CHAR function -

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SR_Creation_Time, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: the entire column value is "SR Creation Time: 17-Feb-2022 11:37:31 CST"